# python call class method to reduce duplicate

Tags: python

I have two scrapy project has many code duplicate 
`project1.py` will crawl whole links
`project2.py` will crawl a few links just for test

I want to modify project2.py for reducing duplicate code

Here is my code structure:

project1.py

```
class MySpider(Spider):

    name = "get_all"
    start_urls = [""]

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        super(MySpider, self).__init__()

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
        yield Request(url=url,callback=self.status_info)

    def status_info(self, response):
        ... 
        yield Request(url=url,  callback=self.project_info)

    def project_info(self, response):
        ...
        yield Request(url=rewards,callback=self.comment_info)

    @classmethod
    def comment_info(cls, response):
        yield item 

    @classmethod
    def spider_closed(cls, spider):
        ...
```

project2.py

```
class MySpider2(Spider):   
    name = "get_uni"
    start_urls = [""]

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        super(MySpider2, self).__init__()

    def parse(self, response):
        ... 
        yield Request(url=url, callback=self.project_info)

    def project_info(self, response):
        yield Request(url=rewards,callback=self.comment_info)

    @classmethod
    def comment_info(cls, response):
        ...
        yield item

    @classmethod
    def spider_closed(cls, spider):
        ...
```

I edit my project2 into :

```
from myproject.spiders.project1 import MySpider

class MySpider2(Spider):   
    name = "get_uni"
    start_urls = [""]

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        dispatcher.connect(MySpider.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        super(MySpider2, self).__init__()

    def parse(self, response):
        ... 
        yield Request(url=url, callback=MySpider.project_info)
```

but get error:

```
File "/Users/obe/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
TypeError: unbound method project_info() must be called with MySpider instance as first argument (got TextResponse instance instead)
```

Where is wrong?
Please guide me,Thank you

Comment: Well, `project_info` is an instance method. Are you sure you didn't mean to call `commet_info` (i.e. `yield Request(url=url, callback=MySpider.comment_info)`). That should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need something like this.

```
from myproject.spiders.project1 import MySpider

class MySpider2(Spider):   
    name = "get_uni"
    start_urls = [""]
    my_spider = MySpider()

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        dispatcher.connect(my_spider.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        super(MySpider2, self).__init__()

    def parse(self, response):
        ... 
        yield Request(url=url, callback=my_spider.project_info)
```

The reason behind this error is when you're calling a method with a parameter named "self", that "self" is referring to the instance of the class, not the class itself. That's why you cannot call the method "statically".

Comment: I put ````my_spider = MySpider()```` out of class.and it can work!What's this method called??